# implement chargen (Character Generator) protocol in C# or java

Tags: c#

I am currently working on one of my college project which requires the implementation of char gen protocol. I need to write a program which will first take the IP address of any host and then it will check that the specified host (whose IP is given as input) supports chargen protocol or not; if that host supports chargen protocol then the program should send chargen requests at port 19 of the remote host and it should also read the reply (characters generated by the host) coming from host. Now the problem is that I don't have any idea about how to implement it in either C# or java; I guess that .Net don't provide any support for this type of stuff; I am not sure about java.

Can anyone please give me any hint on its implementation or is there any external library available which can help me?

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/chargen/CharGenTCPClient.html for Java

Comment: Hi Jaroslav !!! Thanks for the link; it seems good; i hope it will fulfill my requirement ... thanks man :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get familiar with the [Character Generator Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_Generator_Protocol).
2. Study [TCP sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb27wehh.aspx) support in .NET.
3. Code your homework :-)

Comment: The assignment is a pretty simple coding exercise for using the `TcpClient` class. So start from reading about that class in the `System.Net.Sockets` namespace.

Comment: Hi Ondrej!! Thanks for ur reply .. i have a little bit idea of Systems.Net.Sockets but i will explore it in depth ...  Thanks :)